# Removing characters from a string with lengths greater than 2

Tags: c#

Hi have a string which is: 2109389

I want to only keep the first two characters.

So my result will be 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = "2109389";
var sub = s.SubString(0,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "2109389";
return str.SubString(0, 2);
```